# Enviar dados form por array para PHP

Tags: php, array

Devido a uma necessidade do sistema que estamos trabalhando, preciso enviar 3 campos como array para um PHP. Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" />

<input type="text" name="name[]" />

<input type="text" name="name[]" />
```

O que ocorre é que mesmo que eu selecione apenas um, ele traz o resultado informado e os outros em branco. E o count do array sempre retorna 3:

```
Teste DIEGO . Fim
Teste . Fim
Teste . Fim
```

Como poderia tratar para o array somente ter os dados realmente informados? Faço a exibição dessa forma (testando):

```
foreach( $name as $key => $n ) {
  print "Teste ".$n.". Fim<br>";
}
```

Comment: use `empty()` dentro do foreach.

Comment: Pode me exemplificar?

Comment: `if(!empty($n)){echo $n .'<br>'}else{ echo 'valor em branco';}` Acredito que seja isso.

Comment: Acredito que se você proceder dessa forma funcione:
foreach($name as $key => $n){
     if($name[$key] == ""){
            unset($name[$key) ;
     }

Comment: @rray, funcionou a sua resposta, mas a do Wallace Maxters ficou "melhor" pois trata direto no POST. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `array_filter` para  que o php só traga apenas os dados que não estão em branco.

```
$names = array_filter($_POST['names']);

foreach ($names as $key => $value) {

}
```

Veja funcionando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/rc67vB)

A função `array_filter` vai filtrar os valores do `array`, deixando apenas aqueles que não forem vazios. Essa função trata cada valor do `array` da mesma maneira que a função `empty`. Valores como `0`, `'0'`, `''`, `array()` (array vazio) ou `false` serão removidos do `array`.

Se o comportamento acima não é o desejado, você pode ainda definir uma função de callback para `array_filter`. Caso a expressão retorne `true` para o valor do argumento, o item permanecerá. Caso contrário, será removido do `array`.

Veja:

```
array_filter([1, 0, ''], function ($value) {
     return $value !== '';
});
```

o resultado será:

> [1, 0]

Comment: A resposta do @rray deu certo também, mas acho que a tua ficou mais "correta". Obrigado.